# Looking for XML validation language that can handle duplicate element names

Tags: xml, validation, schema

XML Schema doesn't allow duplicate element names at the same level. I'm looking for an XML validation language that can handle that. The XML, which I don't own and therefore can't change, looks something like

```
<items>
    <item type="single">
        <name>Some single item</name>
    </item>

    <item type="group">
        <name>Some group item</name>
        <groups>
            …
        </groups>
    </item>

    <item ref="../item[0]"></item>
</items>
```

As you can, there are three different types of item.

- It is a single item (identified by the attribute type) and has a name.
- It is a group item (identified by the attribute type) and has a name and a groups element.
- It is a reference (identified by the attribute ref)

This is just a simple example, the XML elements are much more complex.
I think I'm looking for a XML validation language that chooses from multiple element definitions.
e.g. if the item definition for single types doesn't fit, try group, if that doesn't fit, try ref and if that still doesn't fit, it's not valid.

Since I want to validate different versions of the XML to find the changes between them, it's really important that the specification is really strict. Meaning, I'll use quantity specifications like *optional* only if it's optional in the XML, not to please the validator.

Comment: [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using XML Schema (XSD) 1.1 by using the feature of "conditional type assignment", also known as xs:alternative. This allows you to define multiple alternative types for the item element, chosen according to the value of the element's attributes.